# How can I safely downcast an int to short?

Tags: java, types, casting

I have the following Java code:

```
shortVar = (short) intVar;
```

But sometimes it's giving me different values than what I expected. 
What is the best way I can protect my code against this case when it is not able to cast properly and throw an error message?

Comment: First check whether `intVar < Short.MIN_VALUE || intVar > Short.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: Test if the value is outside the valid range for short.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know Short class had MAX and MIN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, I'd suggest you should not use the `short` type: It is not recommended by common Java programming rules (due to a low performance in space, because a short occupies 16 bits, while modern architectures work over 64 bits data).

But, only if you must absolutely use `short` variables, the right way to ensure you won't be running out of the proper range is this:

```
    if (intVar <= Short.MAX_VALUE && intVar >= Short.MIN_VALUE)
    {
        short shortVar=(short)intVar;
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        // The cast shall not be safely done.
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You can also use the `short` type for 16 bit unsigned modular addition / modular subtraction (modulo 2^16 of course). But after you're done you may need to convert back to the right signed integer value: `s & 0xFFFF` (where `s` is the `short`) will do that for you. This doesn't directly work for multiplication / division though.